# URI rewriting: handling one page

Tags: url-rewriting

Here's what I'd like to do: make Wordpress think that my *page* called "`toto`" can be called from "`/toto`" but also from "`/toto/{alphanum char}`"

I dont want to make a special rewrite rule, because I dont want to touch the "`.htaccess`" file.

Is there a way to do this in Wordpress?

Comment: You can't do this without adding rewrite rules. You have to use [add_rewrite_rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) .

Comment: WordPress rewrite rules don't use `.htaccess`, all requests get routed to WordPress and URL parsing happens in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You HAVE TO add a rewrite rule to WordPress. That can be done withou touching .htaccess. For example:

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_rewrite_rule');
function cyb_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'toto/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

If you need access to the second part of the URL as query var, you can do this:

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_rewrite_rule');
function cyb_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'toto/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&secondpart=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'cyb_add_vars');
function cyb_add_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'secondpart';   
    return $vars;
}
```

Now "secondpart" is available in the query vars pool and you can access to it using WordPress funcions. For example, imaging you have this URL: "mysite.com/toto/apple"

```
if( get_query_var( "secondpart" == "apple" ) ) {
    //It matchs
}
```